# Symfony 4 Tests

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I want to inject ParameterBagInterface and EntityManagerInterface inside my unit tests (WebTestCase and KernelTestCase), but i couldn't find a method which returns their namespace and name correctly (`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface`). is there a way for doing that?

what i have tried is:

`$this->parameterBag = self::$container->get(ParameterBagInterface::class);`

returns `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ContainerBag`

`$this->parameterBag = $this->prophesize(ParameterBagInterface::class)->reveal();`

returns `Double\ParameterBagInterface\P1`

`$this->parameterBag = $this->createMock(ParameterBagInterface::class);`

returns `Mock_ParameterBagInterface_fccf09f9`

All my classes are using ParameterBagInterface and are type-hinted as such.

Here is example test class:

```
/**
 *
 * @package App\Tests\Entity
 */
class LogCollectTest extends WebTestCase
{
    use CronManagerCron;

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->parameterBag = self::$container->get(ParameterBagInterface::class);
    }

    /**
     * Test saving click
     */
    public function testSavingClick()
    {
        // truncate the log collect table to be sure to get the right click
        $this->truncateLogCollectTable();

        $userAgents = [...];

        foreach ($userAgents as $agent => $expectedResult) {
            // we make fake client requests and record them in database (test enviropment)
            $clientStatus = $this->sendClientData($agent);

            // the controller is resulting properly
            $this->assertEquals(200, $clientStatus);

            /**
             * @var LogCollect $logCollectEntry
             */
            $logCollectEntry = $this->em->getRepository(LogCollect::class)->getLast(); <-- 
        ...
        // later we process this client requests with cron and later assert the data
        $logCollectorCron = new LogCollectorCron(
            $this->container,
            $this->em,
            $this->parameterBag,
            'test'
        );
        $logCollectorCron->run();
        ...
   }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're not gonna get any interface since an interface cannot be instanciated ever, by nature, so to be clear : a ParameterBagInterface object can't exist.
When you ask the container to give you ParameterBagInterface, the container gives you a service that implements this interface.